# Remember which audio device to use for which application?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have a Python program which uses OpenAL for audio.

I'd  like the audio coming from that program to be heard from HDMI speakers, not built-in speakers. I can use Pavucontrol (Pulseaudio GUI) to change that, but I'd like to make the changes permanent (remember after reboot). Either make all OpenAL programs use HDMI by default, or make my program only use HDMI out by default, or everything. I'm assuming each option will require to change a specific configuration file of Pulseaudio or OpenAL.

Minecraft and many video games also use OpenAL so I believe an answer would be helpful to them as well.